# Lost all my stuff

Tags: diablo-ii

Ok, I was just killed and went back trying to recover my body and my stuff and was killed again.

I've lost nearly everything it took me months to collect.

Is there a way to go back to a previously saved set of game data to recover my stuff?

Comment: I assume you're not on ladder, right?

Comment: No, just playing the game by myself.  I was just told by someone at Blizzard that there is no way to recover my stuff.  I had no idea that this could even happen--my stuff has always been there after I was killed.  Pretty sickening to spend all this time on the game just to lose everything.

Comment: Did you start a new game? The corpse with the most "value" is usually sent back to town.

Comment: I was killed and I went back to try and recover my body and was killed again.  So I restarted and all my stuff I had with me when I was killed is now gone.

Comment: I did not know that if I tried to recover my body and was killed again that all my stuff I had with me when I was killed the first time would be lost.

Comment: I've never heard of that happening. Normally if you're killed again you just get a pile of bodies, even if you leave and reenter.

Comment: I'm on version 1.13.  After the second time I died I only had a couple of items on me that I had picked up inadvertently on my way back to recover my body.  It saved those items with my corpse, but not the items I had originally.

Comment: It really sucks that there's no safety measure to prevent losing months of gameplay when someone does something stupid like this.  There's no way I'm going back and trying to find everything again, it's just too much work.

Answer (score 6):

Leave the game and re enter the game.  Your corpse should be with you in town.  If this does not happen, then you may have accidentally '[popped](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Corpse_Popping_Scams)' your body (but this only happens if you are running an old version of diablo 2).

The good thing about not playing online is that you can use an save game editor to give yourself your gear back.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use game editor to do this?

Comment: I'm on a Mac, btw.

Comment: I found something called "Alkor" here--web.nickshanks.com/alkor/.

Comment: Will this work?

Comment: @JamesWinter I do not play d2 on a mac so I'm unable to tell you if it works or not.  Sorry

Comment: @JamesWinter Alkor does look pretty legit though.

Comment: It looks like there are no character editors available for v1.13.

Comment: @JamesWinter that's usually not a problem, if you can create a character from an older version, just edit it and then D2 will automatically port it to 1.13

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work.  I show up in Act 1 with just one item for some reason.

Comment: Alkor merely edits for offline (single player) game's save data. All you need to do is open up your .d2s save file in Alkor. The save files is located in `Applications> Diablo II> Save`. Save when you are done, load up that character, and you should have your modified characters.